# How to check if libraries are unused in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, dependencies, libraries, yarnpkg

I have a lot of libraries listed in my package.json and I know that most of them are unused. How could I know the ones I use and the other one I do not use ?

I am using Symfony 3.4 and Yarn as Dependency Manager

Thanks !

Comment: i guess you need to manually look for the namespaces of the bundles in your src folder, also in your AppKernel.php you see all bundles you actually use

Comment: afaik your actual dependencies should be in the require section of `composer.json` in your project root

Comment: Is it the same way to check if my libraries are used or not ? In fact this is what I want to check, if libraries like bootstrap.css or whatever are used or not

Comment: The reason you are getting rather scattered comments and answers is that Symfony uses composer for it's dependencies while the javascript portion of you code uses yarn.  People are trying to answer your title and not the body of your question.   Might be better to edit and remove the Symfony portion and see if the yarn people can help out.  But I don't think there is really as way to tell because it depends on what your app ends up needing.

Comment: Yes, I was not sure about how to call this... Unfortunately I need to know how to remove those who are unused :/

Comment: Why do you need to remove them?  I know there is a lot but that is more a function of the javascript ecosystem.  They like to make lots and lots of dependencies.  If you are trying to reduce load time then okay but it's doubtful you will get much of an improvement due to caching.  Trial and error is probably your only approach. [yarn why](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/why/) might help.

Comment: I need to remove them beacause of the load time and for more stability. sometimes Im afraid about loading an unwanted resource and being lost then

Comment: The other approach I suppose is to start with no dependencies at all and then start adding one by one.  But I suspect you will end up doing a great deal of work for very little gain.

Comment: yes indeed ! Ok I've seen my problem, i will post another question because I don't understand too this new problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know why a packages is installed, you can run the command [why](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#depends-why-). As example, see this list:

```
>composer show
doctrine/instantiator             1.0.5   A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
phpdocumentor/reflection-common   1.0.1   Common reflection classes used by 
.....
input/output with nice error messages.
```

See the instantiator package

```
>composer why doctrine/instantiator
phpspec/prophecy              1.8.0  requires  doctrine/instantiator (^1.0.2)
phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects  2.3.8  requires  doctrine/instantiator (^1.0.2)
```

You can also try the tree version:

```
>composer why -t doctrine/instantiator
doctrine/instantiator 1.0.5 A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
├──phpspec/prophecy 1.8.0 (requires doctrine/instantiator ^1.0.2)
│  └──phpunit/phpunit 4.8.36 (requires phpspec/prophecy ^1.3.1)
│     └──XXXXXXXX dev-master (requires (for development) phpunit/phpunit ~4.6)
└──phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 2.3.8 (requires doctrine/instantiator ^1.0.2)
   └──phpunit/phpunit 4.8.36 (requires phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects ~2.3)
      └──XXXXXXXX dev-master (requires (for development) phpunit/phpunit ~4.6)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I need to do this but with librariesn  how is it possible ? They are listed in my package.json

Comment: interesting... try remove one and see if the code break

Comment: That was what i was doing but unfortunately I have more than 200 libraries and a lot of pages of code. I will pass a month to clean this :'D

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony front-end and back-end dependencies are kept separately by two different systems. Therefore, unused dependencies are able to be detected with two different tools. The following tools are just an example as more tools with the same functionality exist.

**Front-end:** `package.json`

- https://yarnpkg.com/package/depcheck for yarn
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check for npm

**Back-end:** `composer.json`

- https://github.com/composer-unused/composer-unused

Comment: There is a competing package for composer analysis (incl. unused dependencies):
- https://github.com/shipmonk-rnd/composer-dependency-analyser